# How can I get the traceback of a crash in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

When my game (written using LibGDX) crashes both in the phone or in a virtual device I get the error message: `at com.firstgame.game.firstGame.render(firstGame.java:20)`

this takes me to the 20th line of my code where the

```
public void render() {
    this.render(); // important!
}
```

method is. Is there any way I can get a traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will work but you can try this

```
public void render() {
    try {
        this.render();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```